# " \n"and other redundant data is included in list when using .contents in beautifulsoup"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="pv-entity__degree-info"><h3 class="pv-entity__school-name t-16 t-black t-bold">Universitatea de Medicină și Farmacie „Grigore T. Popa” din Iași</h3>
<p class="pv-entity__secondary-title pv-entity__degree-name t-14 t-black t-normal">
<span class="visually-hidden">Degree Name</span>
<span class="pv-entity__comma-item">MD</span>
</p>
<p class="pv-entity__secondary-title pv-entity__fos t-14 t-black t-normal">
<span class="visually-hidden">Field Of Study</span>
<span class="pv-entity__comma-item">Merdicine</span>
</p>
<!-- --> </div>
```

i have been getting .contents on this div tag.We can clearly see it has 3 children tag.But .contents is giving a list of length 8 when it should be length 3.Why?

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup includes Tags and NavigableStrings in the `.contents`. If you want just tags, you can use `.find_all()` with parameter `recursive=False`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<div class="pv-entity__degree-info"><h3 class="pv-entity__school-name t-16 t-black t-bold">Universitatea de Medicină și Farmacie „Grigore T. Popa” din Iași</h3>
<p class="pv-entity__secondary-title pv-entity__degree-name t-14 t-black t-normal">
<span class="visually-hidden">Degree Name</span>
<span class="pv-entity__comma-item">MD</span>
</p>
<p class="pv-entity__secondary-title pv-entity__fos t-14 t-black t-normal">
<span class="visually-hidden">Field Of Study</span>
<span class="pv-entity__comma-item">Merdicine</span>
</p>
<!-- --> </div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
print(len(soup.div.find_all(recursive=False)))
```

Prints:

```
3
```

Comment: clarification.plz.
1.."recursive" parameter will just exclude desendents of div or will it also exclude direct children if they have same tag?because when running in loop i cant be sure if more than one children have same tag.
2.recursive parameter will exclude the descendents of div and only give results based on direct children like it works with .contents or .children right?

Comment: @NipunTulsyan Yes, `recursive=False` will give you one _direct_ descendants (children) of the element. Without it, `find_all()` will return all tags, subtags, sub-subtags and so on.